# Firefox: paste text from clipboard into input

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firefox, clipboard

I want to have a button to paste some text (from the clipboard) into an input field.

The following snippet works in Chromium, but not in Firefox.

```html
<input>
<button>paste</button>
<script>
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () =>
        navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => document.querySelector('input').value = text)
    );
</script>
```

Is there a way to achieve the same effect in Firefox?

Comment: Firefox only supports reading the clipboard in browser extensions, according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText), so `readText()` will not work for you

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 74+ have hidden testing experiment: `dom.events.testing.asyncClipboard`
(https://bugzil.la/1597857)

Firefox 103+ also changed logic:

- `dom.events.asyncClipboard.readText` enabled present paste option as list menu similar to "right click menu" if we click in button (to avoid these list menu enough is enable with option added to Firefox 74+).
- Older `dom.events.testing.asyncClipboard` no longer works independently - needed enable both.

---

Both still doesn't support privileges by domain like in Chrome but mechanism with additional menu may protect clipboard for now (if we disabled testing version added to Firefox 74+).